# Can I tell the android system that no headphones are currently plugged in?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I know this is a big longshot but here goes. My phone received water damage in the headphone port so currently it always thinks nonexistent headphones are plugged in. This makes it so I can only have conversations on speaker, because otherwise it tries to record audio from a non-existent microphone.

I saw that there is an action called ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG). Is there a way to broadcast that action system-wide in order to "trick" android into thinking there's nothing plugged in, or is this something that one simply doesn't have permission to do?

Something similar to this:

```
Intent().also { intent ->
            intent.setAction("android.intent.action.HEADSET_PLUG")
            intent.putExtra("state", 0)
            sendBroadcast(intent)
        }
```

Comment: curious case ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
AudioManager audioManager = AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.isWiredHeadsetOn();
```

Need to add permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
```

Comment: Unfortunately, isWiredHeadsetOn() is a getter that doesn't actually modify anything, nor does the method setWiredHeadsetOn()